# inject some custom template into a generic form template?

Tags: html, angularjs, templates

I narrowed down a form template to cover a bunch of use cases, but i wanted to dynamically extend it.

I have 5 different controllers which use that template, and wanted to beable to dynamically extend it to fit the now extended needs i have.   The best example I can think of is for one of the controllers i wanted to add a dropdown list to the template to cover the use case.

I wasnt sure the best approach I should go.  I wasnt sure if i should create a new template file:  `newTemplate.html` and somehow require the base template: `add.html`

I was hoping to actually just add something like:

```
<div>
  [[templateExtension]]
</div>
```

which would be a HTML string, or the output from an html file.  I feel there is something else about angular I am unaware of, such as injecting another controller, and then somehow using the injected controllers template and functionality and then doing some assignments.

I am sure there are examples that angular and others have used.  I just was not sure how to go about resolving this issue.

Comment: It sounds like you are unaware of [ng-include](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude). You can use a variable to determine what you include!

Comment: Please make it clear if this question is about AngularJS 1.x (`angularjs`) or Angular 2 (`angular2`).

Comment: angularjs, 1.x    I think I have a solid idea, but what I was not sure if the proper design was to do something like: `<div ng-include="path_to_template"></div>`